# ASP.Net MVC 3 - What is the best way to get logged-in username from within the repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository, membership

I know that you can get the username of the currently logged in user from within the controller by using User.Identity.Name. However, my solution is split in 4 layers (4 projects):

1. MyProject.Domain for the models
2. MyProject.Data for the repositories
3. MyProject.Services where the business logic is
4. MyProject.Web for the controllers, the ViewModels and the Views

Now, my question is what is the best way the get the username of the current user from within the repository.

The thing is that all my models have 4 audit properties: CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate. And I am wondering how to populate the CreatedBy and the ModifiedBy properties when a model is stored to the database.

**UPDATE**:

Here is what I did following the advices I got below. I added an IUser interface in my Domain. I am not sure whether this is the best place to add this, but I decided to put it there, since my domain in referenced by all my other layers. I also added a User class to my controller layer (MyProject.Web), since this class needs access to the HttpContext, and this is the layer where it is accessible. To tell the truth, I did not know where such a class should be added in this layer. I have a Lib directory, so I put it in there.

Then I added a binding in MyProject.Web.App_Start.NinjectMVC3 like this:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    ...
    kernel.Bind<IUser>().To<User>();
}
```

I also added an IUser parameter to my base repository class constructor like this:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    #region Members

    private UpDirContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
    private readonly IUser user;

    #endregion

    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, IUser user)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
        this.user = user;
    }
    ...
```

So now, I can use "user" everywhere in my repositories. It is working, but I am not sure whether this is the best way of structuring things.

I also thought that I could use injection to pass IUser to my base entity class and make sure that the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy properties of my entities would be populated properly from the start, meaning object construction, but then my entities would not have had a constructor with zero parameter, and I did not want that.

**UPDATE 2**:

Here is an example of one of my services constructor:

```
public partial class SectorService : ISectorService
{
    private readonly ISectorRepository sectorRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public SectorService(ISectorRepository sectorRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.sectorRepository = sectorRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    ...
```

I already use injections to get the repositories to the service layer. According to a comment below, IUser should be injected to the service layer, and I am wondering what is the best method to get User passed from this layer to the repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dependency injection, inject an IUser at your composition root (ie your controller's constructor - all the main DI containers support it plius mvc supports it). The concrete implementation of IUser references HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. All of the receivers of IUser don't need to care about where it came from.

I'm not following why though you asked about createdby, etc. Is this a separate question or are you referring to membership information?

Comment: I also prefer to inject an object like IUser where needed (controller constructor or otherwise).  The object's implementation can be in the web project and access HttpContext.  I have used this pattern in projects that may also have a windows service or windows forms application that uses another implementation of the IUser or similar object and have found using dependency injection resolves this issue nicely.

Comment: @Adam_Tuliper: Where I talk about CreatedBy, etc., it is the same question. I am simply explaining why I need the username in my repository. I am using Ninject for my DI. So from what I understand, I should simply add a binding for IUser, and then also add an IUser parameter to all my repositories constructors. I am following you right?

Comment: yes, you got it. Just make sure your binding is through constructor injection ideally on your controller as opposed to resolving somewhere else in code in a lower class. injection should always take place as close to the entry point as possible (the composition root)

Comment: @Adam_Tuliper: I am not entirely sure of what you mean by "Just make sure your binding is through constructor injection ideally on your controller as opposed to resolving somewhere else in code in a lower class". I am still struggling to learn all these patterns while working on projects. I guess I still have a lot of reading to do... Anyway, I updated my post above to explain how I did it. Mayber you can have a look and tell me whether that is what you meant.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp as part of 'good practices' you want to inject as far up in the chain as possible to the point you get control. See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx  so in this case, you should inject your repository (or service layer if your service calls your repository) in the controller's constructor. Then ninject will see the repository required IUser, and instantiate it there as well, so all resolution is being done up front at the very first point your code is getting executed in the controller. Make sense? : )

Comment: @AdamTuliper As a matter of fact, my service layer calls my repository. If I inject IUser to the service layer through my services constructors then, what is the best practice to trickle the User down to the repository? I posted an example of a Service constructore above under "UPDATE 2". I had read that article you sent me. I guess with my level of knowledge on this matter, I would need a full fledged article. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My practice as of late is to pass it from controller -> service, then service -> repository, if necessary. This is because I want two websites (think public facing website and private API website) to use the same models/repositories/services, but the authentication methods for each are different.

Comment: @Stephen_Booher Do you use injection to do so?